# Make r the Subject of the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

Make r the subject of the formula S=πrl+ πr^2.
The answer should be $r=\frac{-\pi l+\sqrt{\pi^{2} I^{2}+4 S \pi}}{2 \pi}$
I cant figure out how they got the answer. Please help

Comment: Do you know how to solve 2nd degree polynomials ?

Comment: You have a second degree polynomial in $r$.  Together with Astyx's answer and expressing your equation $$\pi r^2 + (\pi l)r - S = 0$$ where $a = \pi$, $b=\pi l$, $c = -S$, you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an equation of the form :

$a x^2 + b x  + c = 0$

which can be written :

$(x + {b\over2a})^2 ={b^2 - 4ac\over 4a^2}$

If $b^2 - 4ac$ is positive, you can take the square root, thus :

$x + {b\over 2a} = \pm {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\over 2a}$ ie $x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\over 2a}$